# Detect ARMv8 A53 vs A57 architecture at runtime?

Tags: c, cpu-architecture, arm64

I'm benchmarking a library against ARMv8 machines. I have four Cortex-A53 dev-boards, and our NEON intrinsics implementation outperforms the C/C++ implementation by about 30%. This is expected.

The GCC compile farm offers a Softiron Overdrive 1000. Its a Cortex-A57 server board, and the C/C++ code outperforms the intrinsics implementation by a factor of 50%. This was surprising.

We'd like to use our NEON implementation for A-53, but use the C/C++ implementation for the A57. We have code that can make runtime feature selections, like `HasNEON()`, `HasCRC()`, `HasAES()` and `HasSHA()`. We don't have anything for the architecture, like A53 vs A57.

My question is, how do we detect an A53 vs A57 at runtime?

---

We have similar code for x86 code paths for the P4 processor. The P4 has some slow word operations. We detect the P4 by checking CPUID bits, but ARM systems are different. ARM systems the CPUID-like instruction is reading a MSR, and it usually requires a higher privilege level (EL1 or above).

---

If interested, the Cortex-A57 is slower for a particular hash algorithm because it relies heavily on shifts, rotates and xors. The [A57 Optimization guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/index.html) tells us shifts and rotates are more expensive. It takes 4 or 5 cycle in the ASIMD coprocessor for the shift, and only the F1 pipe can perform the operation (per section 3.14).

It could also be the Cortex-A53 has the same penalty, and its integer unit is slower so non-NEON code does not outperform the NEON code.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Because there isn't  something like CPUID for user programs on ARM.

Comment: @fsasm - We are a Free/Open Source project, so its a cornucopia... Android, Debian, FreeBSD, Linaro, Ubuntu, ... I recently cut-in a change that simply disables NEON on Cortex-A53 and A57. But I'd really like to fix it by disabling NEON code path for A57 at runtime. Also see [Issue 367: BLAKE2b NEON suffers poor performance on ARMv8/Aarch64 with Cortex-A57](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/367).

Comment: In your custom OS, do you have something like cat /proc/cpuinfo?

Comment: Possibly a trivial and off-topic question - but have you ruled out compiler differences? If I remember right, the GCC compile farm Softiron machines default to a GCC 4.8 which has a... suboptimal... implementation of many Neon intrinsics. Checking the code generated by the compiler might be useful, you might find some idioms which worked well for AArch32 are generating more instructions than you'd like with the AArch64 compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, as you and others have noted, the real cpuid-like instructions aren't available from user mode code. In practice, the relevant info is handled in platform specific ways.

On linux, you can try parsing /proc/cpuinfo, if available/readable. The CPU implementer/architecture/variant/part numbers should pretty well identify different CPUs. This file should IIRC also be readable on Android.

For other OSes, the OS would need to provide the necessary info somewhere, and not all of them probably do at all.

EDIT:
A Cortex-A53 that I looked at has got the following info in `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
```

While a Cortex-A57 has got the following:

```
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x1
CPU part        : 0xd07
```

However, as Brendan pointed out, trying to match these is pretty futile as the number of different individual cores constantly grows.

Additionally, some SoCs have a heterogenous set of cores, see [big.LITTLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE). E.g. Snapdragon 810 has got 4 Cortex-A53 cores and 4 Cortex-A57 cores. Your threads will be scheduled and moved across these cores as the kernel's scheduler sees fit. In that case, benchmark numbers that you got at startup might not match the cores that the code ends up scheduled at later.

Comment: *"Snapdragon 810 has got 4 Cortex-A53 cores and 4 Cortex-A57 cores..."* - Wow, that's interesting. I've heard about these [bad] configs on x86 (mismatching different CPUs), but I never encountered them (folks are specifically warned not to do it). It seems Snapdragon broke the mold... We ended up disabling the NEON code for ARMv8 in the problematic case.

Answer (score 3):

Have a `tune()` function that's called during process initialisation, that benchmarks your implementation and GCC's implementation and caches the result (e.g. in a `bool isMyImplementationFaster` global variable).

If your implementation is faster you could assume it's an A53 (and if it's slower you could assume it's an A57). Note that this causes a problem/confusion for CPUs (including future CPUs) that are neither A53 nor A57. However; I'm hoping you'll realise that you don't actually care if it's A53 or A57 (or something else), and that you only care if your implementation is faster/slower.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. There's a problematic use case: distributions. They will package the library for a "minimal" client. However, we also include the fully featured code paths. For example, there will be a C++ implementation of SHA, a NEON implementation of SHA, and an implementation that uses ARMv8 Crypto. SHA is easy to detect since we can probe the CPU and catch a `SIGILL`. The Cortex-A53 vs A57 is trickier. We don't know of cpu probes to do it.

Comment: @jww: How's that problematic? The `tune` function should only choose between code paths when both are available; if a packager included only one code path (A53 or A57) then there's no point in runtime tuning anyway.

Comment: @jww: Any difference (including benchmarked performance difference) is a CPU probe.

Comment: @jww: Perhaps I was too subtle: You are setting yourself up for failure. There's a total of 18 "ARMv8-a" cores now (A53 and A57 are just 2 of many) and this is growing (based on 2016) at a rate of around 4 per year. Each binary test (e.g. if `SIGILL` occurs or not) only halves the possibilities at best. You'd be using information that you need (is an instruction supported, is a sequence faster/slower) to infer worthless information you don't need (which specific core it is) in an bad and broken way, and then using worthless/bad/broken information to "re-infer" the information you started with.

Comment: @jww: Also note that I suspect you may be confusing the issue by conflating 2 separate things - "distribution time" or "compile time" optimisation (e.g. that should be controlled by preprocessor/conditional code - e.g. `#ifdef ARCH_A53`) and "run-time" optimisation (that needs run-time tests). If this is the case; then my advice is to implement run-time tests first; then worry about using conditional code to eliminate unnecessary code (including unnecessary tests) afterwards.